# How do I get these id tags to style properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a website template with multiple pages, an about page, contact page etc.

There is an id tag #subheader assigned to the container for the picture at the top of each page. So it is distributed amongst all the pages. I wanted to change the photo for each page, so I copy and pasted the css for the #id tag and changed the tag slightly for each one. And i hoped to just change the url for each one, and the change the tag name so i could change the html accordingly.

The problem is, the subsequent Id tags always screw up the image. It throws the whole structure out of whack. But the photo acts just fine when i assign the url to the original class.

What am i missing here?

```
  #subheader {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Services.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    #subheader2 {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Architect.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#subheader3 {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Architect.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

`#subheader2`:
[image: #subheader2]
Original `#subheader`: 
[image: Original #subheader]

Here is the full CSS for the #subheader tag.

```
    /* subheader */
#subheader {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Services.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#subheader h1 {
  color: #eceff3;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 00;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
#subheader span {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 88px;
  color: #fff;
}
#subheader .subdetail {
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #777;
  padding-left:0px !important;
}
#subheader .subdetail li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px black;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#subheader .subdetail li a {
  color: #ff6600;
}
#subheader .subdetail li.sep {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
/* subheader end */
```

Comment: screws up the image how? (Can you provide screenshots or expand your explanation).

Also i wouldn't write 3 separate subheader classes/selectors, write a site.css file that contains the style for the subheader across all the pages within the site that way you can be sure it is consistent then on each individual page change the url.

Comment: Are the 3 images all of the same or similar size? Using the same attributes on images of different dimension will produce different results?

Comment: i will add a couple screenshots. I dont see why it should be doing this, the image is the same and it works fine when i add it to #subheader. But If i try to create another id tag (#subheader2) it messes everything up. I attached the shots in my OP.

Comment: Is there code that relies on the id being `#subheader`? (i.e. `#subheader h1 { /*...*/ }`)

Comment: yes! is this a specificity issue? I really dont understand specificity yet.

Comment: oh jeez i think i just figured it out. All the subsequent CSS related to that needs to be added somehow as well!!! duh.

Comment: can anyone help me with an efficient solution to include all the #subheader CSS?  There is #subheader h1 etc etc. I could copy and paste all of this with new id tags, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```css
#subheader {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Services.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#subheader2 {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Architect.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#subheader3 {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background: #222;
  background: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Architect.jpg)top fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

can be reduced to:

```css
.subheader {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #222;
  background-position: top left;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.subheader.services {
  background-image: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Services.jpg);
}

/* H1s specific to services */
.subheader.services h1 {
  …
}

.subheader.architect {
  background-image: url(file:///Users/Nineborn/Desktop/New%20LW%20Construction%20Site/Architect.jpg);
}

/* H1s specific to architect */
.subheader.architect h1 {
  …
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="subheader services">
  <h1>…</h1>
</div>
<div class="subheader architect">
  <h1>…</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i have a bunch of sub ID's? like #subheader h1, etc

Comment: @nineborn My whole point is to move away from the `id` approach. The `class`-based approach is much more flexible for your needs.

Comment: understood. Would you mind looking at the full CSS for the subheader section? Im posting it in my original post. Im wondering if this would change anything about your answer.

Comment: theres all these other classes for the subheader section, im not sure how to apply them easily to all the different pages

Comment: @nineborn I'm away from my machine at the moment but will take a look in a bit.

Comment: @nineborn I looked at the rest of your `CSS`. If you change the `#`s into `.`s (and adjust your `HTML`, accordingly), you should be just fine.